# Mounting Sharepoint on Ubuntu as a Remote Network Location

Tags: networking, microsoft-office, microsoft, office365

For the Office 2016 Sharepoint I would like to mount it to Ubuntu as a remote Network Location.

But following are the limitation

1. WebDAV is disabled in the sharepoint. Also autoversioning is
   disabled.
2. FTP is not available as a protocol. Only HTTPS is the
   protocol.
3. SMB address is also not available. Not sure if Sharepoint
   can be mounted as a smb drive as well.

This is how it works on windows.

1. Sharepoint is mapped as a remote network location on the windows
2. Every boot up time. Credentials need to be put into the location.

Is there any way to do the same?

What should i look into that would possibly solve this problem or give a hint to a solution?

Is this the right platform to ask this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on the sharepoint stackexchange site. It was answered there. 
The link to this answer is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241661/mounting-sharepoint-on-ubuntu-as-a-remote-network-location).

So it turns out any remote location and version system that can be mounted on the windows has to have WebDAV enabled.

This is [where](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.webdav.html) you can further read about it.